# Fast way of loading large corpus of xml files?

Tags: java, xml, lucene

I have a large corpus of xml files (~20,000 files). When I load the entire corpus, it takes me around ~1 sec to load each document. The xmls are pretty large. (> 10,000 lines). Each xml represents a document with nodes for sentences, tokens in the sentence and other similar attributes.

I am using DocumentBuilder in java to load the xml. After loading the xml, I also need to extract some relevant xml nodes (around 100 sentences). For this I used getElementsByTagName().

Is there a faster way to load xml documents in java?

Comment: you mean for loading xml? nothing else.
I am thinking of indexing the xml documents using lucene but wondering if there is an alternative.

Comment: I believe XML is the most efficient file format to be loaded compared to JSON and YAML, as for actual loading why not try multiple methods and do some benchmarking?

Comment: By multiple methods you mean using other XML libraries in Java?

Comment: Consider learning XSLT, especially if it can be streamed.

Comment: @Unihedron, it's the other way around, JSON parsers are usually faster than XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a SAX implementation. SAX is typically somewhat 2 to 5 times faster based on this link: http://dublintech.blogspot.be/2011/12/jaxb-sax-dom-performance.html. It makes a lot of sense when you only need to actually process part of your document and not all contents.

You can also use faster disks like SSDs or maybe a virtual file system with a caching strategy.

If you have slow disks it might even make sense to zip all of them in a big zip which will reduce disk access by 80 to 90%. The unzipping overhead should be offset by the gain in disk access performance.

But saying that you are also considering Lucene actually implies that we are missing some crucial information about your use case, because it implies that the action you are optimize is more or less a 'one off' anyway.

If you really need only a relatively small part of the content of your document you could also consider storing that information in one data structure and serialize it. That way you only need to deserialize one file and not process 20.000 XML documents. In case the documents change you could also store document paths and a hashcode like MD5 to detect modified documents.

Comment: "because it implies that the action you are optimize is more or less a 'one off' anyway" I did not understand that part. I can add more information about my use case if needed.

Comment: Basic question is: are you doing it once during startup of your application? If so, and assuming the application will run for a long time (weeks for a webserver for example) then trying too hard to optimize is maybe not a good idea. Note: I added an alternative solution.